# How to trace my assembly language program?

Tags: assembly, x86, character

I have this code, which checks whether the input is an number or uppercase or lowercase character. However, if I give it anything else than a letter as input should be "non letter."

How can I achieve that?

```
title
.model small
.stack 0100h
.data
entr db "Enter a number : ",'$'
ok db "Nice ",'$'
no db "not a number it is in lowercase case ",'$'
no2 db "not a number it is in Uppercase case ",'$'
.code


mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

MOV AX, 0003h
int 10H

mov ah,09h

lea dx,entr

int 21h

mov ah,01
int 21h

mov bl,al

sub bl,'1'
cmp bl,'9'-'1'
jbe number

sub bl,'A'
cmp bl,'Z'-'A'
jae to

sub bl,'a'
cmp bl,'z'-'a'
jae to3



number:
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset ok
int 21h
jmp @exit

to:
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset no
int 21h
jmp @exit

to2:
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset no2
int 21h
jmp @exit

to3:
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset no2
int 21h
jmp @exit



@exit:


mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h


end
```

Comment: If you're able to check if the value is in one range I don't see why you're having trouble checking if it's in some other range(?). Describe the necessary conditions to yourself in your native (natural) language. Then formalize that into some sort of `IF`-statement in pseudo-code, and finally transcribe that into x86 assembly.

Comment: The answer to the title question is:  **use a debugger**, and single-step the instructions.  This is exactly what debuggers are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not doing something to the outcome of both `sub`'s relies on the byte wraparound and can only works as long as unsigned logic is used via `jbe` and friends.

This is the simplest code you can write to differentiate between any case letters and all the rest:

```
 sub al, 'A'
 cmp al, 'Z'-'A'
 jbe Letter           ;It's uppercase
 sub al, 'a'-'A'
 cmp al, 'z'-'a'
 jbe Letter           ;It's lowercase
NonLetter:
 ...
Letter:
 ...
```

Note that your 2nd subtraction must not use 'a' (=97) because the 1st subtraction already subtracted 'A' (=65). Thus here only the complementary value is needed. 97 - 65 = 32

Comment: sir your given code works but the main problem is to determine the upper case and lowecase i try my old cmp 

My code

sub bl,'A'
cmp bl,'Z'-'A' :uppercase
jae to

sub bl,'a'
cmp bl,'z'-'a'  :lowercase
jae to3

but it always jump in lowercase

Comment: I think it's even simpler to `or al, 0x20` to force letters into the lower-case range, and then do one sub/cmp.  I guess it comes down to what kind of simplicity you're looking for.  Copying `al` to another register before doing each `sub`/`cmp` would be a more obvious but less efficient way to do the checking (and avoid having to get the `'a'-'A'` constant right)

Answer (score 0):

The code you show us won't even correctly differentiate between letters and other characters!
You should surely **do something** with the outcome of the subtraction.
You should also change the conditional jump because now you've excluded the 'Z' character.

This is the code you need to differentiate between **uppercase letters** and all the rest:

```
sub rply+2, 'A'
jb  notok
cmp rply+2,'Z'-'A'
ja  notok
```

Comment: Sir i try to implement your code but when i try to run it it only shows capital if i input a small a                                                                                   sub ah, 'A'
 jb ok
 cmp ah,'Z'-'A'
 ja ok
  sub ah, 'a'
  jb notok
 cmp ah,'z'-'a'
 Je notok

Comment: You don't need the `jb`.  Values less than `'A'` will wrap to a high unsigned value, so the `cmp` / `ja` will catch them, too.  gcc uses this "unsigned compare trick" to optimize things like `if(a > 10 && a < 20)`, even for signed `a`.